# how to resolve this error in JOGL "failed to create a pipe screen for i965"

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am new started to work with JOGL.
I am working on Linux and
When I put the following code in eclipse

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
    import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
    import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
    import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
    import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;

    public class BasicFrame implements GLEventListener {

       @Override
       public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
          // method body
       }
       @Override
       public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
          //method body
       }
       @Override
       public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
          // method body
       }
       @Override
       public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
          // method body
       }
```

and this code for main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

          //getting the capabilities object of GL2 profile
          final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
          GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
          // The GLJpanel class
          GLJPanel gljpanel = new GLJPanel( capabilities ); 
          BasicFrame b = new BasicFrame();
          gljpanel.addGLEventListener(b);
          gljpanel.setSize(40, 40);

          //creating frame
          final JFrame frame = new JFrame (" Basic Frame");

          //adding canvas to it
          frame.getContentPane().add( gljpanel);
          frame.setSize(frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
          frame.setVisible(true);

       }//end of main

    }//end of classimport
```

I get the following error

**libEGL warning: failed to create a pipe screen for i965**

How was this problem solved?

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the drivers, not a programming issue.

Comment: Hi Saeed, [this](http://forum.jogamp.org/libEGL-warning-failed-to-create-a-pipe-screen-for-i965-td4032959.html) thread may be useful. Which gpu and driver are you using?

Comment: Hi elect, i am using Intel 4 Gen Integrated. I do not use  my Nvidia graphics card. @elect

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: no @elect i am using linux mint 17.2

Comment: Where is it thrown exactly? At which line?

Comment: @elect  
i think my machine can not create java frame or jogl frame